# reverse the words in same String[]?

Tags: java

I was asked this in one of the interview.

how  to reverse the words in string in java? Example:  String[] s ="Cat sat on sofa" will turn to s ="sofa on sat cat"  modifying  the same s

I said :

public String reverse (String[] s){

```
    String reverse = "";
    for(int i = (s.length -1); i>=0; i--)
    {
    reverse = reverse + s[i] + " ";

    }
    return reverse;
    }
```

the interviewer further said i am not suppose to use any string variables e.g. string reverse = ""; I need to modify the same input String[] s = {The cat sat on sofa}.

Comment: That is not an array, but a String. Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: I wouldn't state it's a duplicate, OP wants to reverse string in-place without any helper objects. And this is not possible in Java without some tricks which he doesn't want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code from a link I provided for you. Take a look at this link there are multiple ways of doing this. Although remember Strings are immutable and you can't really do it unless you cast or use char etc.

```
public String reverse(String s) {
    String reverseStringVariable = "";
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i != -1; i--) {
        reverseStringVariable += s.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverseStringVariable;
}
```

http://www.brilliantsheep.com/3-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify string object at all, because it's **immutable**. If you want to do something like reversing words in-place, it's better to use array of char.

Comment: Thanks jdevelop. I was asked this in one of the interview and i wrote the same code on the white board. the interviewer further said i am not suppose to use any string variables e.g. string reverse = ""; I need to modify the same input String[] s = {The cat sat on sofa}.

Comment: That might mean interviever is not qualified in Java at all, or he was expecting you to say that strings are immutable so his task can not be solved without some dirty tricks with reflection or classpath hacking. And it's better to work on char arrays then.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void reverse(String[] s) {  
     if(s == null || s.length <= 1) {  
         return;  
     }  
     String temp = null;
     for(int i = s.length(), j = 0; i > j; i--,j++){  
          temp = result[j];  
          result[j] = result[i];  
          result[i] = temp;    
     }  

}
```

Comment: Can their be a way to reverse String[] s without using String temp = null?